# UIBarButtonItem greyed out

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I am adding two UIBarButtonItems to a UINavigationBar. The first of these is a system item - the search button - and works great. The second is a custom image (a small white Glyphish icon), but when I add this the image becomes grey. The button is perfectly clickable, just grey. Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

[image]

I do believe the alpha levels are correct. If I put the same icon in a UIBarButtonItem on a UIToolbar (rather than a UINavigationBar) this is how it appears:

[image]

Comment: Not getting it. Perhaps you could add a picture. (never touched i-phone dev though).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Olof. I added a pic.

Comment: If it's a custom icon you could check the alpha value again?

Comment: @Darwin, I think the alpha value is okay because it shows up properly in other uses. I added a pic of it on a UIToolbar.

Comment: Are you creating the button in code or in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, try cleaning the target.

Shift + cmd + K

Comment: Thanks Darwin, that did it! I'm writing that one down :)

Comment: Yep. :) Had the same problem with an `UIImageView` a while ago. See: Sometimes it's the __details__: "I had been using a grey icon earlier."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is in a highlighted state? If you're creating this button programmatically you might want to check if its `UIControlState == UIControlStateHighlighted`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a toolbar type icon image. That Glyphish icons on toolbars and TabBars only use alpha layers. But if you are building a button you have to use a standard image. Open the image in any image editor and use the colors you want for your button and the transparent values for alpha layer where you want. It is, in some way, the inverse to the images made of alpha layers in tabbars.

Comment: It seems to be working now without any modification. I just had to use a white icon instead of grey, but somehow Xcode retained the old icon. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I had been using a grey icon earlier. When I realized it was the wrong color, I suffixed the file with "-grey" and brought in a white icon, which took over the name of the grey icon. But somehow Xcode was still retrieving the old icon, despite its name being changed in the project (and thus in the Finder). Cached maybe? It's a mystery to me!

Thanks for your input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to force reload button.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([sender isKindOfClass:UIBarButtonItem.class]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *button = sender;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    }
}
```